How to generate a companion object in Scala 3?
I have several enums where there companion object code is identical to one another.
How can I generate these companion objects where the difference between them is just the enum name?
enum Variants:
  case A, B, C, D, ...

enum Groups:
  case I, II, III, IV, ...


/** Same for Groups and all other enums **/
object Variants: 
  import zio.json.*
  /* ZIO */
  given JsonCodec[Variants] = JsonCodec[Variants](
    JsonEncoder[String].contramap[Variants](_.toString),
    JsonDecoder[String].mapOrFail(name =>
      Try { Variants.valueOf(name) }.toEither.left.map(_.getMessage)
    )
  )

  /* Tapir */
  import sttp.tapir.*
  given Codec[String, Variants, CodecFormat.TextPlain] =
    Codec.derivedEnumeration[String, Variants].defaultStringBased

  /* Quill */
  import io.getquill.MappedEncoding
  given MappedEncoding[Variants, String](_.toString)
  given MappedEncoding[String, Variants](Variants.valueOf)


It possible to generate encoders with a trait (see below), but
this approach breaks native derivation where a type should be sealed or enum, such as in Tapir's Codec.deriveEnumeration.
object Variants extends EnumSupport { override type T = Variants }
object Groups  extends EnumSupport { override type T = Groups }
trait EnumSupport:
  import io.getquill.MappedEncoding
  import sttp.tapir.*
  import zio.json.*

  type T <: scala.reflect.Enum & scala.Product
  def valueOf(n: String): T

  /* ZIO */
  given JsonCodec[T] = JsonCodec[T](
    JsonEncoder[String].contramap[T](_.toString),
    JsonDecoder[String].mapOrFail(name =>
      Try { this.valueOf(name) }.toEither.left.map(_.getMessage)
    )
  )

  /* Tapir */
  given Schema[T] = Schema.string[T]
  given Codec[String, T, CodecFormat.TextPlain] =
    Codec.parsedString(this.valueOf)

  /* Quill */
  given MappedEncoding[T, String](_.toString)
  given MappedEncoding[String, T](this.valueOf)



What about using derive?

With customized derivation like here it might be easier to use object Type extends EnumImplicits[Type] where trait EnumImpicits[Type] { def valueOf(..) } would define all these givens. The trick would be in the right type bounds definition so that all necessary methods would be available. Or some Enumeratum + derivation from Enum type class.

trait would break Tapir's derivations,

As far as I can tell, it works: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/MateuszKubuszok/6vfS0QdkTteXpCiIQKhLOQ/2

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/UE7ezjhSTuWshT7CvYKChw - here is an example which won't compile inside a trait

Defer derivation with inline https://scastie.scala-lang.org/MateuszKubuszok/V6mpONaCTWKsVJ7DkYEsKg
